# Jython Swing Table

Tags: swing, jython

I'm very new to Python, Jython and Swing.  I'm writing a procedure, in Jython, to display a table of financial items. I need to know which row has been selected so that a second window can be opened in order to edit those details.

I've searched and am confused as to what to do next. This is the code I've written in order to show the table:

```
from java.awt import *
from javax.swing.table import DefaultTableModel
from javax.swing import ListSelectionModel as LSM
from javax.swing import JFrame
from javax.swing import JTable
from javax.swing import JScrollPane

class MDTable(DefaultTableModel):
    def __init__(self, data, headings) :
        DefaultTableModel.__init__(self, data, headings)

    def isCellEditable(self, row, col) :
        return 0

class ReminderTable:
    def __init__(self, tabledata):

        frame = JFrame("Reminders")
        frame.setSize(1500, 1000)

        colnames = ('Start Date', 'Description', 'Last Paid', 'Next Due', 'Frequency', 'Amount', 'From Account', 'To Account' )

        self.table = JTable(MDTable(tabledata, colnames))

        self.table.selectionMode = LSM.SINGLE_SELECTION
        self.table.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(0)

        scrollpane = JScrollPane()
        scrollpane.setViewportView(self.table)

        frame.add(scrollpane)
        frame.setVisible(True)
```

What do I need to add in order to discover which row has been (double) clicked?

Comment: Don't know anything about jython, but in pure Swing you would use a `MouseListener`. Start by reading the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Write a Mouse Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html).

Comment: I've looked at these pages previously.  I'm only just getting to grips with Jython and have no knowledge of Java.  I understand that I need to add a Listener but don't know how to convert the Java code into Jython. I'm truly baffled!

Comment: Those pages show you exactly what to do and have working examples. If you can't understand that I'm not sure how you expect us to help. So why are you using jython? Learn one language (Java/Swing) at a time.

Comment: I don't have to explain to you why I'm using Jython.  I came here looking for help and advice. If you can't help fine.  I require help not criticism and  put downs!

Comment: I did give you advice. I suggested you need to use a MouseListener and pointed you to an example. And then suggested maybe learning/understanding the basics of Swing first would help with jython since you still need to use Swing methods to set properties of the table and access the data in the table etc... If you want so use Jython, then it is easy to search the web for examples now that I suggested you need a MouseListener. Did you try keywords like "jython mouselistener"? YOu will find some basic examples. If you don't understand them post the code your tried.